# Fast way to filter spam messages from maildir?

Tags: spam, maildir

I have a Maildir with about 50k emails, about 42k of which are spam (the result of leaving my domain and email up and not using it for 2 years).

I have the following script to try and filter out spam:

```
#!/bin/sh
for email in "$@"; do
  if ! spamassassin -e < "$email" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    mv "$email" /tmp/spam
  fi
done
```

But this is taking **forever**!

The device I am only able to do this on is limited, it's a NAS with an arm processor...but still!

Is there possibly any faster way to do this? At the moment, workingon a subdir with 1000 files, it's been going for almost 12 hours and found 36 spam messages...

Comment: Where's the bottleneck?

Answer (score 3):

You may start `spamd` daemon in "local tests only" mode and test messages using `spamc` command.  It should eliminate huge part of `spamassassin` initialization e.g. parsing perl and configuration files.

Running network tests for huge number old messages (up to two years old) is not cost/time effective IMHO.

AFAIR on my old laptop processing one message in "local only mode" takes spamc around 0.3s (three messages per second or 10_000 messages per hour), processing one message in "network mode" take usually 5-7s over mobile broadband connection.  It would be a good idea to run a few network tests in parrallel during mass checks.

You will find a [summary of performance related topics in the spamasassin manual](https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/FasterPerformance).

---

```
#!/bin/sh
for email in "$@"; do
  # SCORE - "12.7/5.0" on success OR "0/0" on error
  SCORE=`spamc -c < "$email" > /dev/null 2>&1`
  # EXIT - 1 on spam detection, 0 on not-spam or error 
  EXIT=$?
  if [ "$EXIT" = "1" ] ; then
    mv "$email" /tmp/spam
  fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that sounds like a huge improvement!

I am not familiar with spamassasin at all, and have no idea how to do that. Would you be willing to provide some mroe steps or a link? If not, no issue, I will figure it out, thank you :)

Comment: Which OS (Linux distribution) do you run on th NAS?  `spamd` configuration & startup depends on it.  BTW I sometimes start "personal spamd" on my non privileged user account and access it over unix socket.